# SQL query with SUM on column in JOINed table

Tags: sql, join, sum, derby

I have two tables in a derby database that I want to query together.

```
Orders
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
| ID | UserID | PurchaseDate | TotalPrice |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
|  1 |    1   | TIMESTAMP    |    7.00    |

OrderItems
+---------+-----------+----------+
| OrderID | ProductID | Quantity |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|    1    |      1    |     2    |
```

I want a query to return all the info on the order from the Orders table as well as the total number of product associated with that order.

I tried this thinking it would work but get the error - "Column reference 'ID' is invalid. When the SELECT list contains at least one aggregate then all entries must be valid aggregate expressions."

```
SELECT 
orders.ID, orders.UserID, orders.PurchaseDate, orders.TotalPrice, SUM(Quantity) 
AS productCount
FROM app.orders JOIN app.orderItems ON orders.ID=orderItems.OrderID
```

Comment: dunno why someone downvoted me.  Pleas explain how went against site practices for reference

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT 
app.orders.ID, app.orders.UserID, app.orders.PurchaseDate, app.orders.TotalPrice, SUM(app.orderItems.Quantity) 
AS productCount
FROM app.orders JOIN app.orderItems ON app.orders.ID=app.orderItems.OrderID 
group by app.orders.ID, app.orders.UserID, app.orders.PurchaseDate, app.orders.TotalPrice
```

Comment: I get the following error when I try this:


Column 'ORDERS.ID' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'ORDERS.ID' is not a column in the target table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a group by clause like :

```
GROUP BY orders.ID,orders.UserID,orders.PurchaseDate,orders.TotalPrice
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you will encounter this problem

> Column 'table.columnName' is invalid in the select list

because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause.

The `group by` clause is missing.

Use

```
GROUP BY orders.ID, orders.UserID, orders.PurchaseDate, orders.TotalPrice
```

Comment: This seems to duplicate an existing answer from 2012